# I want to use "PieChart", "ComboChart" and "Control"

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to use "PieChart", "ComboChart" and "Control" in a such way that "Control" would be able to adjust "Pie" and "Combo". The problem starts when my Database in like this:

```
 ['Name', 'Age', 'date', 'ville'],
        ['Michael' , 12, 2012, 'A'],
        ['Elisa', 20, 2012, 'B'],
        ['Robert', 7, 2012, 'A'],
        ['Michael', 54, 2013, 'A'],
        ['Elisa', 22, 2013, 'E'],
        ['Robert', 3, 2013, 'F'],
        ['Michael', 42, 2014, 'G'],
        ['Elisa', 33, 2014, 'H'],
   ['Robert', 42, 2014, 'G']
```

I wish "ComboCahrt" to perform like what this link illustrates:
 https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

Having such the output, we need to retrieve a query for the "ComboChart". My script is found in this link
http://jsfiddle.net/alirezamoussaei/SNRRr/1/

I will be appreciated it if you could make changes to correct the code:
  ...
 P.S: I employed "BarChart" in my code. Please let me know how to change it to "ComboChart".

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code (see 
http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/qRt7e/) such that it appears to work as you are requesting.  The key is that a single control can be bound to more than one chart using e.g.

```
bind([control], [barChart, pieChart])
```

Once you do this, don't also draw the pieChart separately, but let the dashboard draw it for you.

The BarChart can function as a combo chart just by specifying different chart types for individual series. The top level chartType option just provides the default chart type.  You could say 'ComboChart' instead, and then the default is a line chart.

- Docs on combochart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart
- Docs on ChartWrapper: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject